# how do get all records based on an associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Customer. Customer has_many Messages. Messages have text as a field.

I would like to find all customers with a message with specific text. All text will be slightly different but will have some consistent words that I want to search for. For example:

> "hello my name is john"

For each customer the name in the sentence will be custom, but I want to find all customers with "hello my name is" in the text. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Customer.includes(:messages).references(:messages).where('messages.text LIKE ?', "hello my name is %")
```

Comment: As a slight follow up, how do I find the single Customer in that list that the message was last sent to?

Comment: Assuming your message table has the timestamp columns, `Customer.includes(:messages).references(:messages).where('messages.text LIKE ?', "hello my name is %").order('messages.created_at DESC').first`